# Jquery Jtable listAction not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I have a jtable like this:

```
$("#EncuestasTablaContenidos").jtable({
                title: "Tabla de Encuestas",
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                actions: {
                    listAction: '../../srvEncuestas?parAction=listarEncuestas',
                    updateAction: '../../srvEncuestas?parAccion=editarEncuestas'
                },
                fields: {
                    numeroencuesta: {
                        title: 'Numero de Pregunta',
                        width: '5%'
                    },
                    PreguntaEncuesta: {
                        title: 'pregunta',
                        edit: true
                    }
                }
            });
```

My problem is that `listAction` is not being put in the servlet. I already tested the URL so it's not that. I think it's the Jtable plugin, but I need some help. Any comment would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment, but did you add the load function call after the jtable configuration?

```
$("#EncuestasTablaContenidos").jtable({
   title: "Tabla de Encuestas",
   paging: true,
   pageSize: 10,
   actions: {
      listAction: '../../srvEncuestas?parAction=listarEncuestas',
      updateAction: '../../srvEncuestas?parAccion=editarEncuestas'
   },
   fields: {
      numeroencuesta: {
          title: 'Numero de Pregunta',
          width: '5%'
      },
      PreguntaEncuesta: {
         title: 'pregunta',
         edit: true
      }
   }
});

$("#EncuestasTablaContenidos").jtable("load"); //this line will actually load the data
```